# Comparar 2 fechas en mysql y obtener diferencia de dias entre ambas

Tags: mysql

quiero hacer una consulta que me saque cuantos días de diferencia hay entre 2 fechas que paso.
La query es la siguiente:
 `select datediff("28/09/2020",curdate());`

Me da problemas porque la fecha necesita estar en formato y/m/d pero no consigo transformar la fecha "28/09/2020" a dicho formato con lo cual me falla la query. He probado poniendo el parametro "day" pero tampoco funciona. He probado con date_format pero lo mismo, solo acepta transformar de 'y/m/d' a 'd/m/y'.
Es decir, necesito que esta fecha '28/09/2020' pueda pasarla a '2020/09/28'

imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, si pueden ayudarme se lo agradeceria.

Comment: ¿De dónde sale la fecha 28/09/2020? Tal como lo planteas, simplemente puedes cambiar el formato manualmente. Otra cosa es que sea una aplicación que envíe la fecha a MySql, probablemente sea allí donde tengas que tratarla.

Comment: la fecha está en un campo de la bbdd que tengo, necesito hacer una query que compare esa fecha con la fecha actual y ver si han pasado 4 dias. Intente hacerlo con el date_format pero no funciona, solo funciona cambiar la fecha si es desde año mes dia. @RogerTorné . Muchas gracias por tu respuesta de todas formas!!

Comment: Y el campo donde tienes la fecha a comparar, ¿De qué tipo de datos es? ¿varchar?, 
 ¿date?

Comment: el campo es tipo date pero de momento le estoy pasando la fecha a pelo para hacer las pruebas, y aun asi no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

El formato de la fecha que estás pasando no es correcto.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),"2020-09-28"); //Devuelve 2

SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_FORMAT(mydate,'%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Comment: gracias @Carmen por tu respuesta. El formato está bien porque lo que necesito es poder convertir esta fecha "28/09/2020" en esta --> "2020-09-28" para despues poder compararlas con la funcion DATEDIFF(). No se como convertirlo

Comment: @javierlenza Si en un campo date, como indicas, usa date format para que tenga el mismo formate que CURDATE(), para ver este formato haz SELECT CURDATE(); en tu base de datos, generalmente es yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: lo he intendado pero el date format no me funciona, me provoca un NULL si intento convertirlo a ese formato, si no te refieres al date format, no se entonces como podria hacerse.

Comment: Qué sale cuando haces SELECT CURDATE();?

Comment: el resultado de hacer esa query es:    2020-09-30

Comment: Pues entonces la sentencia es SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_FORMAT(aqui-el nombre-de-tu-campo,'%Y-%m-%d')) FROM aqui-el-nombre de tu tabla WHERE aqui-las condiciones-si hay;

Comment: No me funciona, lo he hecho a pelo dado que he cogido una fecha que estaba en el campo que quiero. Adjunto imagen del error en la descripcion de arriba

Comment: @javierlenza debes usar guiones en el formato de la fecha dentro de datediff porque debe tener el mismo formato que curdate para poder hacer la operación, es independiente de en que formato obtengas tu fecha

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, hacer los formatos de fecha con DATE_FORMAT: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Después hacer el DATEDIFF con el mismo formato de fecha que has indicado anteriormente: [https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php#:~:text=GMT%20%2B8%20hours](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php#:%7E:text=GMT%20%2B8%20hours))-,DATEDIFF()%20function,date%20portion%20from%20each%20expression.

También se encuentra un ejemplo de DATEDIFF, pero CURDATE va como primer parámetro: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/datediff.php

En tu caso, quedaría como de esta forma:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '2020-09-28');
```

Comment: Por qué no mejor citar documentación oficial?

Comment: @BetaM Hecho en el último link, hay varias referencias a funciones DATE.

Answer (score -1):

En que formato está el campo fecha de la base de datos?
Los campos que quieres comparar estan en los dos en la misma tabla?

Comment: Hola @juan martinez sanz, el formato esta en formato fecha pero aun asi las pruebas las estoy haciendo a pelo, no le estoy pasando el campo, le paso directamente la fecha de momento. La fecha que le paso es -> 28/09/2020 y necesito compararla con la fecha actual y me saque los dias de diferencia.

Comment: creo que lo que estas buscando es esto
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2020-03-01', GETDATE());